# Examples of symplectic automorphisms of $M$ that set-wise preserve a Lagrangian submanifold $L$

Tags: symplectic-geometry

I’m interested in finding interesting examples of non-Hamiltonian automorphisms of a symplectic manifold (not necessarily closed - but preferably so) $(M,\omega)$ that set-wise preserve a Lagrangian sub manifold $L$.

For example, given a Lagrangian sphere, we can define a (symplectic) Dehn twist along it which would set-wise preserve the sphere. Are there other examples like that?

Is such a property important for some reasons?